# Load string containing words from file

Tags: c, string, file, struct, file-io

I need to load strings from file into a struct array.

> **CORRECT OUTPUT:**
>
> ```
> 4
> Sarajevo,345123
> Tuzla,123456
> Mostar,101010
> Banja Luka,234987
> ```
>
> **MY OUTPUT:**
>
> ```
> 1
> Sarajevo 345123
> Tuzla 123456
> Mostar 101010
> Banja Luka 234987,544366964
> ```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct City {
  char name[31];
  int number_of_citizen;
};

int load(struct City cities[100], int n) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("cities.txt", "r");
  int i = 0;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%[^,]s %d\n", cities[i].name, &cities[i].number_of_citizen)) {
    i++;
    if (i == n)break;
    if (feof(fp))break;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return i;
}
int main() {
  int i, number_of_cities;
  struct City cities[10];
  FILE* fp = fopen("cities.txt", "w");
  fputs("Sarajevo 345123", fp); fputc(10, fp);
  fputs("Tuzla 123456", fp); fputc(10, fp);
  fputs("Mostar 101010", fp); fputc(10, fp);
  fputs("Banja Luka 234987", fp);
  fclose(fp);
  number_of_cities = load(cities, 10);
  printf("%d\n", number_of_cities);
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_cities; i++)
    printf("%s,%d\n", cities[i].name, cities[i].number_of_citizen);
  return 0;
}
```

Could you explain me how to fix this? Why my program only loaded 1 city?

Comment: `scanf()` is not the right tool for the job. Try `fgets()` instead.

Comment: BTW: why isn't the last character of the text file a newline? :-)

Comment: it was deliberately done in a college online environment

Comment: To help diagnose mistakes like this, it is very helpful to always check the return value of `scanf`.  eg `while( 2 == fscanf(fp, "%[^,]s %d\n" ...))`. If you check for `feof` after the loop and discover that you are not at the end of input, you can emit an error message indicating that the input was invalid.  As a general rule, you should *always* check the value returned by scanf so that you know how many conversions were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fscanf()` conversion string is incorrect: instead of `"%[^,]s %d\n"` you should use:

```
while (i < n && fscanf(fp, "%30[^,],%d",
                       cities[i].name,
                       &cities[i].number_of_citizen) == 2) {
    i++;
}
```

Or better:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int load(struct City cities[], int n) {
    char buf[200];
    int i = 0;
    char ch[2];
    FILE *fp = fopen("cities.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", "cities.txt",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    while (i < n && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%30[^,],%d%1[\n]",
                   cities[i].name,
                   &cities[i].number_of_citizen, ch) == 3) {
            i++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid record: %s\n", buf);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

Also change your `main` function to output commas between the city names and population counts:

```
int main() {
    int i, number_of_cities;
    struct City cities[10];
    FILE *fp = fopen("cities.txt", "w");
    if (fp) {
        fputs("Sarajevo,345123\n", fp);
        fputs("Tuzla,123456\n", fp);
        fputs("Mostar,101010\n", fp);
        fputs("Banja Luka,234987\n", fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    number_of_cities = load(cities, 10);
    printf("%d\n", number_of_cities);
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_cities; i++)
        printf("%s,%d\n", cities[i].name, cities[i].number_of_citizen);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** since there are no commas in the database file, you must use a different parsing approach:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int load(struct City cities[], int n) {
    char buf[200];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("cities.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", "cities.txt",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    while (i < n && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        /* locate the last space */
        char *p = strrchr(buf, ' ');
        if (p != NULL) {
            /* convert it to a comma */
            *p = ',';
            /* convert the modified line */
            if (sscanf(buf, "%30[^,],%d",
                       cities[i].name,
                       &cities[i].number_of_citizen) == 2) {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid record: %s", buf);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I get 0 as result, could you fix it?

Comment: did you try to compile it with my main function? it scanned all cities with invalid record...

Comment: @codproe: The `printf` statements do not output a `,` between the city names and the population counts.

Comment: I cannot change main function, that main is from our online environment autotester

Comment: Then the format cannot be parsed effectively with `scanf()`

Comment: @codproe then why do you use `,` as separator for reading input if there is no `,` in the file? That won't work

Comment: @codproe: What is your online testing environment? The `main()` function is seriously deficient.

Comment: main function was deliberately written with some purpose of practice

Comment: Wouldn't `%[^0-9]%d%1[\n]` be OK? The last line would only return 2 matches instead of 3, then.

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you very much, that worked, but now I have for every name of city one extra space, could you help me to fix it?

Comment: @codproe just check if the last character is a space and replace by 0 byte?

Comment: @codproe: use my updated function. Try and understand how it works too.

Comment: @chqrlie your function goes into infinite loop

Comment: @chqrlie this would work correctly https://prnt.sc/VHk01UX3sfcr

Comment: @codproe: you should use `"%30[^0-9]%d"` to avoid potential buffer overflows.

Comment: @codproe: my mistake: missing `s` in `sscanf` :)